Weird jumps in DSC measurements between scans
I have multiple DSC measurements with multiple up- and down-scans and some of the time, seemingly at random, the inflection points will show massive jumps in the heat flow. I have no idea where they come from, since when I repeat the measurements they are not reproducible. But they happen often enough for it to incur considerable time loss and annoyance. Can anyone tell me where these come from? Are these common? How can I prevent them in the future?


Could it be a lag or an issue with the sample itself (like bubbles)?

@MelanieShebel Assuming a solid (e.g., crystalline) sample, the material is ground briefly for instance in an agate mortar and pestle that «enough» sample fits into the little crucibles (Al is one typical material for a sweep as depicted). You close them, weight them out, pierce the lid with a needle, insert them side-by-side to your reference into the oven, shut this lid, open the gentle nitrogen gas flux, launch the heating ramp (example video by Mettler). For a spontaneous evaporation (like superheating), the circled peaks are bit [too] large.

This is confusing. You apparently have two different experiments, each with the same starting material? In each experiment you perform two cycles? What instrument are you using? Sample, etc?

this is one and the same sample. the first upscan melts (blue) it, the second measures the glass transition (red), the third measures the glass transition again (pink) to make sure it hasn't shifted (kinetic influences, partial decomposition etc.) Bubbles is a good idea since the melt has a very high viscosity and the glass transition shows pronounced ?enthalpic lag?

The peaks of the blue trace are around $\pu{50 ^\circ{}C}$ (actually both at $t = 0$), the ones of the purple trace around $\pu{120 ^\circ{}C}$ -- check first that the programmed ramp doesn't start / end the heating / cooling sweep right at these temperatures.  The ones around $\vartheta \ge \pu{380 ^\circ{}C}$ perhaps are the upper threshold you requested for your (I presume organic) sample(s) and can reflect the switch of the electronics to start the next sweep.
To increase the value of a DSC reported (especially cyclic DSC), equally state the heating / cooling rate.  An initial screening of an alloy with a ramp of $\pu{10 K/min}$ can be fine; to monitor closely a phase transition of an organic sample, a rate of $\pu{2 K/min}$ might be acceptable.  The rate eventually picked depends on your sample, and available instrument time.  Results of preliminary tests (capillary test,heating stage microscope, etc) can guide the setup of the DSC, too.
Peaks pointing to $-q$ indicate exothermic processes, typically the solidification of a liquid, perhaps to yield a crystalline material.  How much supercooling occurs (i.e. the difference of melting temperature, and temperature of solidification) largely depends on your sample composition and purity but equally on the cooling rate. Supercooling can be observed with compounds as simple as water, and organic compounds and solutions, too (for instance benzoic acid).  It indeed is an instructive example to cool distilled water in a test tube immersed in a water ice bath, and to monitor the temperature of your sample.
Differentiate the curves.  Around $\pu{325 ^\circ{}C}$, the purple traces exhibit a somewhat wider bump of an endothermic process.  Melting would be an example except in absence of concurrent sample decomposition, first order phase transition yield sharp signals.  More likely are gradual loss of crystal water / solvent molecules enclosed in the sample (which can be spot by a thermogravimetric analysis, TGA); (partial) recrystallization processes (e.g., compounds consisting of small [organic] molecules), or glass transitions (e.g., organic polymers).  In materials science, the two later processes can be of interest for an in situ characterization of crystalline polymorphs e.g., to complement a cyclic DSC by temperature variable powder X-ray diffraction analysis (an example, and an other).

I'm sorry, but this doesn't address my question at all and is just a short essay on general best practices in DSC measurements. It reads like an AI generated answer...

While it isn't AI, the most plausible cause for me for the circled peaks is right at the start: the definition of start/end point of heating and cooling ramp (e.g., to start at 50C, or 150C instead of ambient temperature -- maybe there was a good reason for this which wasn't shared [yet]).
